# Access 2016 processing duplicate mail to Outlook via VBA

Tags: ms-access, outlook, vba

I have an Access 2016 database with tables that hold student data. I have managed to successfully send an email to each recipient using VBA-Outlook (the code works), however, it looks to have sent the the email to the same recipients multiple times (random duplicate of 1 to 4 emails per recipient).

I can confirm that there are no duplicate `[E-mail Address]` whatsoever contained within the `Student` table.

When I use `.Display` instead of `.Send` in my `oEmailItem`, there does not appear to be any duplicates. Perhaps I should include a *waiting period* of 1 second in the loop?

`On Error Resume Next` is used to bypass the null value returned by blank email fields; not everyone has an `[E-mail Address]` in this table

Why is this code sending random duplicate email to recipients?

```
Private Sub SendEmail_Click()

Dim rS As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbS As DAO.Database
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Folderpath As String
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem
Dim myemail As String
Dim Subjectline As String

Subjectline$ = InputBox$("Please enter the subject line for this mailing.", _
"We need a Subject Line!")

Set dbS = CurrentDb()
Set rS = dbS.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Students")

Do While Not rS.EOF
On Error Resume Next
myemail = rS![E-mail Address]

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
End If

'Set the email template
Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\MailTemplate\Mail1.oft")

With oEmailItem
    .To = [myemail]
    .Subject = Subjectline$
    .Send
End With
'End of emailing

rS.MoveNext
Loop
Set oEmailItem = Nothing
Set oOutlook = Nothing
Set rS = Nothing
Set dbS = Nothing

End Sub
```

**Update:**
Thanks HiPierr0t. Your answer showed me that I wasn't emptying the variable at the end of the loop; thus assigning the previously used `[E-mail Address]` when met with a null or blank email field.

I did have to keep

`Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\MailTemplate\Mail1.oft")`

inside the loop however (strange, must be a MS thing).

I ended up removing `On Error Resume Next` as it does create more problems, and used

> > `myemail = Nz(rS![Email Address], vbNullString)`

to change any null or blank fields into `""`. That way, I don't need to empty to variable each time as the lookup changes it to `""` if it's null anyway. The If..Else takes care of the rest.

```
Do While Not rS.EOF
'On Error Resume Next
myemail = Nz(rS![Email Address], vbNullString)

Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\MailTemplate\Mail1.oft")

If myemail = "" Then
    rS.MoveNext
Else
    With oEmailItem
    .To = [myemail]
    .Subject = Subjectline$
    .Display
    End With
    'End of my emailing report
    rS.MoveNext
End If
Loop
```

Comment: Googled around a bit. Another user fixed a similar issue by putting the code in a module. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/9e071151-c812-47d3-86b9-4e5f342517ee/vbscript-sends-excel-outmail-macro-message-twice-bug?forum=ITCG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`On Error Resume Next` tends to create more problems than it solves.

If no email exists, your code goes on. However your variable *myemail* is still filled with the previous email you sent an email to.

1- Make sure to empty your variable after the email is sent with `myemail = ""` or `myemail = vbNullString`.
 2- Before sending the email, check that *myemail* is not empty with an `If` statement.
 3- You may want to place your code below outside of the loop. It won't make a big difference but there is no need to process this part of code every time.

```
If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
End If

'Set the email template
Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\MailTemplate\Mail1.oft")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you’ve emptied the myemail before sending e-mail.

Also you need to add “rS.Close dbS.Close” after the Loop.

Here is complete code:

```
Private Sub SendEmail_Click()

Dim rS As DAO.Recordset
Dim dbS As DAO.Database
Dim Filepath As String
Dim Folderpath As String
Dim oOutlook As Outlook.Application
Dim oEmailItem As MailItem
Dim myemail As String
Dim Subjectline As String

Subjectline$ = InputBox$("Please enter the subject line for this mailing.", _
"We need a Subject Line!")

Set dbS = CurrentDb()
Set rS = dbS.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM Students")

Do While Not rS.EOF
On Error Resume Next
myemail = ""
myemail = rS![E-mail Address]

If oOutlook Is Nothing Then
    Set oOutlook = New Outlook.Application
End If

'Set the email template
Set oEmailItem = oOutlook.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\MailTemplate\Mail1.oft")

With oEmailItem
    .To = [myemail]
    .Subject = Subjectline$
    .Send
End With
'End of emailing

rS.MoveNext
Loop

rS.Close
dbS.Close

Set oEmailItem = Nothing
Set oOutlook = Nothing
Set rS = Nothing
Set dbS = Nothing

End Sub
```